# How to bootstrap/initialize couchDB at first run?

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I can't find any information on initalizing a couch db. What's the best method of initializing and creating the map and view functions for couchdb at deployment?

I have a node server which will access a couchdb. Should I just create the http calls necessary to create the proper logic on couchdb from my node server or is there a better way handling the initialization of the db?

`EDIT`: Also is there any good open source projects that I can take examples from?

Comment: I used the [`nano` library](https://github.com/dscape/nano) and wrote a setup script that tests whether the database exists and if not, it creates the database, reads the views from a js file, and adds them as a design document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure your question is clear.  Remember that CouchDB is schemaless, so, at startup, there probably isn't anything (ie, documents) on which to base view functions.

If you mean a helper to setup a design document with attachments and the like, in addition to the other answers, have a look at Kanso (http://kan.so). If you're comfortable with Node, you'll find it friendly.

If, on the other hand, you're looking for something to analyze existing docs in a CouchDB and guess at good views, I've haven't come across that yet.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use [erica](https://github.com/benoitc/erica).